# Vuejs + nginx resolve backend url in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose

My aim is to have a docker-compose file where frontend container can communicate with backend, while access to backend-api not exposed through the frontend proxy.
By default backend endpoint `:8080/api/v1/`.

*Link to the repository at the end of the post.*

**Solution 1:**

**Problem is that UI users can access api backend through the frontend, e.g `curl localhost:3000/api/v1/users`.**

I found a working solution where the frontend makes loopback to upstream which follows to the backend.

**Question:** Could you recommend me a better approach on how to restrict(or not expose) access to backend-api through frontend? Other words, request to `localhost:3000/api/v1/users` should return 400.

*frontend config - .env.production*

```
export const API_URL = "/api/v1/";
```

*default.conf*

```
upstream backend-api {
  server backend:8080; #service in docker-compose
}
server {
  listen            3000;
  location / {
    root      /app;
    index     index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
  location /api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend-api;
  }
  ...
}
```

**Solution 2 (Work in progress):**
The solution does not work for now.
I think nginx default.conf is incorrect.

I do believe that I can use the docker DNS, but I keep getting `GET http://backend:8080/api/v1/users net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` on frontend application.

**Question:** How to resolve docker DNS inside nginx server block?

*frontend config - .env.production*

```
export const API_URL = "http://backend:8080/api/v1/";
```

*default.conf*

```
server {
  resolver          127.0.0.11;
  listen            3000;

  location / {
    root      /app;
    index     index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  error_page        500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root      /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

Link to the repository: https://github.com/zhenik/vue-prod-example

**EDIT 1**
I found another way of how to restrict backend with Solution 1 above, you will need two things:

1. Authentication system (like AWS Cognito, Firebase, etc...).
2. Nginx [ngx_http_auth_request_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html)

Nginx config will look like:

```
location /api/v1/ {
    auth_request /auth;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_pass http://backend-api;
  }

  location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_method      POST;
    proxy_set_header  Token $http_Token;
    proxy_pass        http://auth-api/auth;
  }
```

Comment: If the call is made in javascript by vue-js, then it's executed in the client, on a user browser. The browser (user computer / mobile / ...) is not inside the docker network and cannot access the docker DNS, only accessible by containers inside a same docker network. Therefore it would never be able to resolve http://backend:8080.

Comment: That said, you could : 1/ use a proxy (nginx / traefik / ...) onto a container inside both a bridge docker network and the backend container network (if the backend network is not bridge) that could resolve backend:8080, but this proxy has to be exposed on a host port (ex: 3000). Then calls to localhost:3000 will go through the proxy, be redirected to the backend container. Your first solution. 2/ you could read about server side rendering (SSR) and execute JS code (and AJAX calls) on the server.

Comment: Thank you @QuentinPetel, thas for sure I am lacking knowledge about server/client side rendering.